# draw an arc with two different colors in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I am working on a canvas. I want to draw an arc with a different two-color, like first half will be green second half will be red.
sample code

```
// CANVAS
const canvas = document.getElementById('bar'),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;

// CANVAS PROPERTIES
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

const x = width / 2,
    y = height / 2,
    radius = 41,
    circum = Math.PI * 2,
    start = 2.37, 
    finish = 75; 
  let curr = 0; 
const raf =
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = raf;

function animate(draw_to) {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, start, draw_to, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  curr++;
  if (curr < finish + 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      animate(circum * curr / 100 + start);
    });
  }
}

animate();
```

code link https://jsfiddle.net/gowtham25/bp0myt21/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const x = canvas.width / 2
const y = canvas.height / 2
const radius = 41
const start = -25
const end = 75
const width = 6

function DrawArc(x, y, radius, start, end, width, color) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.lineWidth = width
  ctx.strokeStyle = color
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, start, end, false)
  ctx.stroke()
}

function DrawGauge(percentage) {
  const rotation = Math.PI * 0.75
  const angle = Math.PI * 1.5
  const current = angle * percentage / 100

  DrawArc(x, y, radius, rotation, rotation + current, width, 'green')
  DrawArc(x, y, radius, rotation + current, rotation + angle, width, 'red')
}

function Animate(percent = 0) {
  if (percent < 0) return
  if (percent > 100) return
  DrawGauge(percent)
  requestAnimationFrame(() => Animate(++percent))
}

Animate()
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I recommend breaking down the things you want to draw into functions at the very least so you can easily draw the item by passing in the parameters each time and can reuse the function to draw multiple different versions of that item.

Personally I'd create a class for the arc drawing and a class for the gauge drawing and then the gauge would draw two arcs based on the value of its percentage property. That way the drawing is separated from your data logic which is extremely important as you start doing more complex things with more draw calls.

Comment: Coyale that arc is look like pixeled. How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// CANVAS
const canvas = document.getElementById('bar'),
      width = canvas.width,
      height = canvas.height;

// CANVAS PROPERTIES
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

// CANVAS PROPERTIES
const ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx2.lineWidth = 1;
ctx2.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx2.shadowOffsetY = 0;

var x = width / 2,
     y = height / 2,
     radius = 40,
     circum = Math.PI * 2,
     start = 2.37, 
     finish = 50; 
      
  let curr = 0; 
  
const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
      window.requestAnimationFrame = raf;

function animate(draw_to) {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, start, draw_to, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  curr++;
  if (curr < finish + 5) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      animate(circum * curr / 100 + start);
    });
  }
}

function animate2(draw_to) {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.arc(x, y, radius, start, draw_to, false);
  ctx2.stroke();
  curr++;
  if (curr < finish + 5) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      animate2(circum * curr / 100 + start);
    });
  }
}

animate();


setTimeout(function(){ 
 finish = 52;
  start = 5.5;
 ctx2.strokeStyle = 'red';
 animate2();
}, 2000);
```

```css
#bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bar" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

The question is not clear at all! I am not sure but maybe someting like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/15srnh4w/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **startAngle** parameter in 
*ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle [, anticlockwise]);*
Currently, if you modify the strokeStyle without changing the startAngle it will just draw on the same path.

https://jsfiddle.net/97ogkwas/4/

```js
// CANVAS
const canvas = document.getElementById('bar'),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;

// CANVAS PROPERTIES
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

let x = width / 2,
    y = height / 2,
    radius = 41,
    circum = Math.PI * 2
    start = 0.5* Math.PI
    finish = 75; 
  let curr = 0; 
const raf =
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = raf;

function animate(draw_to) {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.beginPath();
   if(curr>45){
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        start = 1* Math.PI;
       
    }
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, start, draw_to, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  curr++;
  if (curr < finish + 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
  
      animate(circum * curr / 100 + start);
      
    });
  }
}

animate();
```

```css
#bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bar" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/97ogkwas/4/